# Chromium not loading CSS

Tags: chromium, css

It happens sometimes, on slow connections, that `chromium-browser` goes timeout while loading a webpage.

Then, the page is shown without CSS.

Afterwards, it is impossible to reload page with its CSS.

**No success** with following solutions:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+R
- Cleaning cache
- `sudo apt install --reinstall chromium-browser`

Is there a way to recover this?

Comment: spell-checking ... sudo apt-get ... !

Comment: Thanks! It also works only with `apt`. No clue why :-)